# Angular 7 reactive form how to reset the form and get its initial values instead of resetting them to empty values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular7

Is there a way to reset a reactive form group into its initial values instead of get it empty using `.reset()` method ?

I have the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-brxfth), where the default selected value is `Parent`, and if the user change it to sister, and wants to get the form to initial value, click on reset button to do so.

Currently, I tried:

```
this.formGroup.reset();
//Or
this.formGroup.markAsPristine;
//Or
this.formGroup.markAsTouched
```

The `.reset()` reset the form completly.

P.S. Some people may say that the user can re-select the default value instead of clicking on reset button. But in my case, I have a huge user form where he needs to update his information, and he may needs to reset to initial values if he was mistaken in some values.

Comment: Why not adding  `this.formGroup.get('family_relation').setValue(1)` at the end of `reset()` method?

Comment: It is a form control array with several rows and multiple form control. I think it is not a good idea to set manually the value of each of them

Comment: As of Angular 13 you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70461013/651555

Answer (score 59):

You can save the form initial values:

```
this.initialValues = this.formGroup.value;
```

And then pass those values to the reset function:

```
this.formGroup.reset(this.initialValues);
```

Answer (score 9):

Tou should make control nonNullable
// If this flag is set, the control will instead reset to the initial value.

```
const cat = new FormControl('tabby', {nonNullable: true});
cat.reset();
```

cat.value is "tabby"

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just setting it as `nonNullable` will reset it to the initial value that was set when the form was created.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy That's an implementation with strictly typed forms which is available from Angular 14 and not Angular 7 like the question asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Please find the stackbliz here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ciztu9

Angular Provides reset(formState:any = null), you can pass the initial formState/object as a first parameter

For more info https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset

Answer (score 3):

Create a method `setForm()` which will be called in the constructor and `reset()`

```
setForm() {
  this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    'family_relation': new FormControl(this.familyRelationArray[0]['family_relation_id'])
  });
}
```

(Remove the code from the constructor which set the initial values)

`resetForm()` now looks like:

```
reset() {
    this.formGroup.reset();
    //Or
    this.formGroup.markAsPristine;
    //Or
    this.formGroup.markAsTouched

    this.setForm();
  }
```

And the constructor:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.familyRelationArray = [
      {
        family_relation_id: 1,
        family_relation_type: 'Parent'
      },
      {
        family_relation_id: 2,
        family_relation_type: 'Sister'
      }
    ];
    this.setForm();

  }
```

Comment: It is better to use inside ngOnInit ?

Comment: Sure! then take the `this.setForm()` from the c'tor and place in `ngOninit()` voila

Comment: It is a form control array with several rows and multiple form control. I think it is not a good idea to set manually the value of each of them

Comment: Well you will have to if you want to use the "initial" default value

Answer (score 2):

Each FormControl has a readonly property `defaultValue` that will be used to reset the value when the control is being reset without a explicit value.

Normally when creating a new FormControl the defaultValue will be set to `null` but when passing `{ nonNullable: true }` as the options argument the `defaultValue` will be set to the initial value you pass to the control.
Calling reset without an argument will now reset the control to the initial value.

```
const value = 'my initial value';
const formControl = new FormControl(value, { nonNullable: true });

formControl.reset(); // Resetting to initial value.
```

---

### Note:

See also the comment inside the `FormControl` class at the `defaultValue`:

```
/**
 * The default value of this FormControl, used whenever the control is reset without an explicit
 * value. See {@link FormControlOptions#nonNullable} for more information on configuring
 * a default value.
 */
readonly defaultValue: TValue;
```

More information from the `FormControlOptions` at the `nonNullable` property:

```
/**
 * @description
 * Whether to use the initial value used to construct the `FormControl` as its default value
 * as well. If this option is false or not provided, the default value of a FormControl is `null`.
 * When a FormControl is reset without an explicit value, its value reverts to
 * its default value.
 */
nonNullable?: boolean;
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be other ways of doing it, but I would do it using one of following methods:

**Method 1:** Passing values to the reset method.

```
reset() {
  this.formGroup.reset({family_relation: 1});
  //Or
  this.formGroup.markAsPristine;
  //Or
  this.formGroup.markAsTouched;
}
```

**Method 2:** Setting values

```
reset() {
  this.formGroup.reset();
  //Or
  this.formGroup.markAsPristine;
  //Or
  this.formGroup.markAsTouched;
  // this.formGroup.get('family_relation').setValue(1)
}
```